# mkdir with sed in bash script

Tags: bash, sed, mkdir

I want to create directories which names should correspond to a list of zipped files in the parent directory. Additionally I want to get rid of the file extension in the resulting name of the directory.

e.g. archive01.gz should result in a directory with name archive01

My script so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.gz; do
    echo $file | sed 's/.gz//' | mkdir
done
```

The error message is:

```
mkdir: missing operand
```

However,

```
echo $file | sed 's/.gz//'
```

results in the correct name for the directory. How do I pipe it to mkdir?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better way to do this would be to use [parameter substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) instead of a pipe/subshell:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.gz; do
    mkdir ${file%.gz}
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.gz; do
    echo "$file" | sed 's/\.gz//' | xargs mkdir
done
```

Answer (score 2):

mkdir doesn't work with pipes. Try the following:

```
mkdir `echo $file | sed 's/.gz//'`
```

The ` evaluates and then replaces it with the answer. It's called command substitution and alternatively could also be written as:

```
mkdir $(echo $file | sed 's/.gz//')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use command substitution as

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.gz; do
     mkdir $(echo $file | sed 's/.gz//')
done
```

**OR**

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.gz; do
     mkdir `echo $file | sed 's/.gz//'`
done
```